# elixir iex shell start error

Tags: erlang, elixir

When I type iex command to start Elixir shell, it prompts the following error, I have no idea what is wrong, tried to reinstall erlang and elixir, but not works.

The error message :

```
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-    threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

*** ERROR: Shell process terminated! (^G to start new job) ***

=INFO REPORT==== 8-Apr-2015::17:55:56 ===
application: elixir
exited: {bad_return,
            {{elixir,start,[normal,[]]},
             {'EXIT',
                 {{badmatch,{error,enotsup}},
                  [{elixir,start,2,[{file,"src/elixir.erl"},{line,34}]},
                   {application_master,start_it_old,4,
                       [{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,272}]}]}}}}
type: temporary

=INFO REPORT==== 8-Apr-2015::17:55:56 ===
application: syntax_tools
exited: stopped
type: temporary

=INFO REPORT==== 8-Apr-2015::17:55:56 ===
application: compiler
exited: stopped
type: temporary

=INFO REPORT==== 8-Apr-2015::17:55:56 ===
application: crypto
exited: stopped
type: temporary

=ERROR REPORT==== 8-Apr-2015::17:55:56 ===
Error in process <0.27.0> with exit value: {{badmatch,{error,{elixir,     {bad_return,{{elixir,start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{{badmatch,{error,enotsup}},[{elixir,start,2,[{file,"src/elixir.erl"},{line,34}]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,"application_master....
```

Comment: Just a general comment Peter.  When you report these sorts of issues, it's really helpful if you identify (at a minimum) the OS (with its version), the version of Erlang and the version of Elixir. Better yet, take a look at this: [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elixir v1.0.3 does not work with Erlang 17.5. You need to either update Elixir to v1.0.4 or downgrade Erlang to 17.4.

Comment: it would be nice if the error message is more explicit, checking the minimum erlang version required rather than crashing.

Comment: That's what we would do if it wasn't due to incompatibility issues that we couldn't have foreseen.

Answer (score 0):

the error enotsup denotes an operation not supported on your platform. check if elixir is correctly compiled, the error occurs at the very beginning of the elixir startup.